# Expiry Date Notification

Tags: swift

IM a Newbie at programing and very new at swift I have been self teaching my self thro udemy and youtube .

I was curious if some one could show me some simple code to Make a Expiry Notification. I just want the app to notify the phone when the date on a card expires. So far I have a table view that you can add cards to with expiry dates and upload a picture of the card to the view controller. I haven't been able to figure out how to get the same pic to save to the table View cell yet either.

I really appreciate every ones help Thank you very much

I really love learning how to program with swift if anyone has and pointers or great tutorials I would love get my hands on those thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to write the code for you but I can you some pointers. What you need to do is to use `NSCalendar` to generate a date from month/day/year values of your desired date using NSDateComponents and the `NSCalendar` method `dateFromComponents`.

I assume that you want to create a local notification? (Those display on the notification screen even if your app isn't running.)

Under iOS 8 you have to use the `UIApplication` method `registerUserNotificationSettings` to ask the user for permission to display local notifications.

Then you need to create and schedule your local notification. The class is called `UILocalNotification`. You create one using it's init method, then set various properties including `fireDate`, `alertTitle`, `alertBody`, `soundName` (if desired), etc. (You'd set fireDate to the date you created from the user-entered month/day/year.) Then you call `UIApplication.sharedApplication.scheduleLocalNotification()` to schedule the notification.

Comment: Thank  you so much for your time to help me out .